# Map object in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am new in React Native. Right now, I am studying Props and State. I wanted to try the FlatList Component in this doc https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist. However, I am getting this error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using typed JavaScript known as Type script.

If you want to use TypeScript (I highly encourage it, then you can do so by following below tutorial):

> Migrating to TypeScript:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2018/05/07/using-typescript-with-react-native

> To just get rid of the error!

```
state = {selected : (new Map())};
```

TypeScript Migration Continued...

**Adding TypeScript**

The next step is to add TypeScript to your project. The following commands will:

- add TypeScript to your project
- add React Native TypeScript Transformer to your project
- initialize an empty TypeScript config file, which we'll configure next
- add an empty React Native TypeScript Transformer config file, which we'll - configure next
- adds typings for React and React Native

Okay, let's go ahead and run these.

```
yarn add --dev typescript
yarn add --dev react-native-typescript-transformer
yarn tsc --init --pretty --jsx react
touch rn-cli.config.js
yarn add --dev @types/react @types/react-native
```

The tsconfig.json file contains all the settings for the TypeScript compiler. The defaults created by the command above are mostly fine, but open the file and uncomment the following line:

```
 {
  /* Search the config file for the following line and uncomment it. */
  // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
}
```

The rn-cli.config.js contains the settings for the React Native TypeScript Transformer. Open it and add the following:

```
module.exports = {
  getTransformModulePath() {
    return require.resolve('react-native-typescript-transformer');
  },
  getSourceExts() {
    return ['ts', 'tsx'];
  },
};
```

**Migrating to TypeScript**

Rename the generated App.js and __tests_/App.js files to App.tsx. index.js needs to use the .js extension. All new files should use the .tsx extension (or .ts if the file doesn't contain any JSX).

If you tried to run the app now, you'd get an error like object prototype may only be an object or null. This is caused by a failure to import the default export from React as well as a named export on the same line. Open App.tsx and modify the import at the top of the file:

```
-import React, { Component } from 'react';
+import React from 'react'
+import { Component } from 'react';
```

Some of this has to do with differences in how Babel and TypeScript interoperate with CommonJS modules. In the future, the two will stabilize on the same behaviour.

At this point, you should be able to run the React Native app.